# Resolving pseudo domain name to private IP

Tags: dns, ip, hosts, domain

Assume I have a VM running on OSX with private IP 10.0.0.1 which can be accessed from the host machine.

I was wondering how can I map a pseudo domain, `*.app.dev`, to the private IP on my host machine so that on my host machine I can resolve the domain `*.app.dev` to 10.0.0.1.

The purpose of this setup is to have virtual environment for development and not pollute my host machine with unnecessary packages and services.

edit: I realize that `/etc/hosts` can accomplish non wildcard domain names, I should have been more clear and mention wildcard domain names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

Dnsmasq is a very small DNS server usually used as a proxy. It offers a lot of ways to manipulate DNS lookups, one of which is to respond to all DNS queries for a domain with a single IP.

The example dnsmasq.conf file has specific example for this:

```
# Add domains which you want to force to an IP address here.
# The example below send any host in double-click.net to a local
# web-server.
#address=/double-click.net/127.0.0.1
```

The following 2 lines are all that you would need to get running

```
server=8.8.8.8
address=/app.dev/10.0.0.1
```

*(You can change the `server` parameter to whatever upstream server you want. Or use `resolv-file` to use a resolv.conf file)*

Then just configure your system to use `127.0.0.1` as a DNS server.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, (with the help of http://bhamrick.com/2013/04/18/setup-a-wildcard-tld-using-dnsmasq-on-os-x/) I was able to achieve the desired outcome!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add the following line to `/private/etc/hosts`:

```
10.0.0.1  app.dev
```